# Prevent words such as 'the' from appearing at the end of the line

Tags: line-breaking, typography

I write my document in Latex for Mac and I don't know how to prevent Latex from putting 'the' and similar short words at the end of the line. I already tried [`impnattypo`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/impnattypo) and [`encxvlna`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/encxvlna) packages, but none of them worked. Any ideas, please?

Comment: A tedious way would be to replace each instance of `the ` by `the~`. There must be better ways...

Comment: Are you using `babel` with the correct language specification?

Comment: Yes, I use \usepackage[english]{babel}. Is it ok that way?

Comment: @nika yes, it is OK.  Is this line breaking occurring a lot, or is it just a one case thing?

Comment: You're planning to open Pandora's box. If I see it correctly, the two packages mentioned were tailored for contexts in which *single letters* at the end of a line are considered unacceptable. You seem to be thinking about words that are 3 or more letters long, and that occur very frequently in English texts. If you tied all these words to the words succeeding them (which may be short words themselves), you'll be seriously messing up the appearance of your paragraphs, as you're reducing the number of breaking points that TeX may use. The result is likely to look awful.

Answer (score 8):

> Any ideas, please?

not the kind of answer you may be looking for, but: an idea -- of what the result may look like when 3-or-less-letter-words are prevented from finishing a line.

```
\documentclass[DIV=12,12pt,paper=a5,pagesize]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. What's happened to me?, he thought. It wasn't a dream. His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls. A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame.

\newpage
One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he~found himself transformed in~his~bed into a~horrible vermin. He~lay~on~his armour-like back, and~if~he~lifted his~head a~little he~could see~his~brown belly, slightly domed and~divided by~arches into stiff sections. The~bedding was~hardly able to~cover it and~seemed ready to~slide off~any~moment. His~many legs, pitifully thin compared with the~size of~the~rest of~him, waved about helplessly as~he~looked. What's happened to~me?, he~thought. It wasn't a~dream. His~room, a~proper human room although a~little too~small, lay~peacefully between its~four familiar walls. A~collection of~textile samples lay~spread out~on~the~table - Samsa was a~travelling salesman - and~above it~there hung a~picture that he~had~recently cut~out~of~an~illustrated magazine and~housed in~a~nice, gilded frame.

\end{document}
```

[image]