# Have the first word of a sentence appear at the beginning of the next line instead of at the very end of the line

Tags: formatting, line-breaking

I don't want a sentence to start at the end of a line with just one word, especially a very short word, like "It", "As", "The", etc. 
It interrupts the flow of reading and just looks ugly.

Edit: After reading some comments, I added an example of what it looks like in MS Word, just to clarify: 
[image: Quote from Wikipedia] 
(Quote from Wikipedia)

Is there a way to have this automated for the whole document? I wrote a 100 page paper and I'd rather not do it manually for each case, if there was another way.

I learned that this is to be avoided, but I even find this all over scientific papers, like the random one I show below. There is obviously still space at the end of the paragraph, so the "In" could easily be placed in the next line. (Not to discredit this paper, which I haven't even read!)

Edit: If this concept is new to you, I don't want to make you insecure about your writing style! It might just be my personal aesthetic preference, really. Also note that I first learned to avoid this writing German, not English.
[image: I highlighted the passage.]

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you "learn this is to be avoided" when you see "this all over scientific papers"?

Comment: @Werner Not helpful. Why bother reply? 
To clarify: I didn't say every paper does this, I doubt the majority does it. I have no statistics on this. I was surprised to find this happening in papers at all. I never see it in newspapers or books. Also, I explained why I don't want this right at the beginning of my question.

Comment: what do you want to happen to the line before the break? end short (as if with `\\ `) or still be justified with extra white space (as if with `\linebreak`) ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The second!

Comment: by far the most reliable way would be to edit the source, with a regular expression such as  `\s+([a-zA-Z][a-z]?)\s+` to ` \1~`  every one or two letter word will be followed by tilde if it was followed by space

Comment: @ulrich.liebig: Are you using LuaLaTeX? I think it should be possible to deal with this using a custom `pre_linebreak_filter` filter.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your helpful answer! I'll try this. I still look foward to other suggestions as well.

Comment: @wilx I don't use LuaLaTex, but thanks.

Comment: This question seems related, though not the same problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113198/prevent-words-such-as-the-from-appearing-at-the-end-of-the-line?rq=1

Comment: You write: ‘There is obviously still space at the end of the paragraph, so the "In" could easily be placed in the next line.’ But the problem is not the space at the end of the paragraph, it's that pushing “In” to the next line will make too wide interword spaces, which is much worse, from a typographic point of view.

Comment: My theory is, the one guy who figured out how to do this in LaTex was then bought by Microsoft to make this the no-brainer it is in MS Word. Really frustrating.

Comment: @ulrich.liebig: Where is MS Word is there an option to avoid this behaviour? And who "figured this out in LaTeX"? Where are you getting your information from?

Comment: If you look at the second line of the first page of the introduction to (a randomly selected) book called [*Typography: Design and Practice*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=e5MkzETNcsgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=typography&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), you'll see the end of the line as 'The' starting a new sentence. Now I have no idea if this book is any good -- it was just the first link I clicked on when I searched for 'typography' in Google Books. It makes me wonder, too, where you got this information from about typographic practice. (Was it about English typography?)

Comment: Oops, sorry, bad link. I meant to link to page 11: https://books.google.ca/books?id=e5MkzETNcsgC&lpg=PP1&dq=typography&pg=PA11#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @jon I learned this with regards to German (my paper is in German, too). I can't name a book, it's just what I picked up from teachers. I find it equally unappealing in English, though. When I was using MS Word, I always avoided this without thinking much of it. That is why I wonder how to do it now. I do see papers that seem to be written in LaTex but have avoided this, too (could be coincidence).

Comment: I added another image to my question to make it clearer. Thanks to all who tried to help so far!

Comment: Also, I do not know whether there is "one guy who figured it out", that was meant to be a joke, I would have thought an obvious one. My apologies

Comment: [Another example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46128876/GalileoGalilei.jpg) of an ancient book (1666) that contains several instances of three-letter words following a comma at the end of lines, to show that this was never regarded as something to be avoided, even in the old days.  The link is taken from [this post](http://www.guitex.org/home/forum/5-tex-e-latex/100860-idea-di-un-nuovo-pacchetto-per-colophon-in-stile-antico?lang=en#100869) appeared on the [Italian TuG](http://www.guitex.org/) some time ago.

Comment: Hmm, it does seem less common in the German articles I have at my disposal, but it is certainly seems like 'try to avoid it if possible' and not 'never, ever do this'. As egreg says, if you aren't careful, avoiding every instance of this 'rule' is likely to lead to even worse typographic results. That said, as a technical problem, I think David's solution is a practica one (unless you use LuaTeX).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; please continue this conversation [in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44269/discussion-on-question-by-ulrich-liebig-have-the-first-word-of-a-sentence-appear).

Answer (score 7):

You mention that you don't use LuaLaTeX. The following answer may, hopefully, still be of use to other readers of this posting who are willing and able to use LuaLaTeX.

The solution sets up a Lua function that prohibits a linebreak immediately following 1-, 2-, or 3-letter words which (a) follow a punctuation mark and (b) begin with an uppercase letter. A few examples: A, I; Am, As, At, Be, By, Do, He, In, Of, Or, Us, We; And, Are, For, Her, His, She, Now, The. The Lua function is assigned to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback; it thus runs at a very early stage of processing, *before* TeX's usual processing kicks in.

Operation of the function is suspended if the text occurs inside a verbatim-like environment such as `verbatim` (provided by the LaTeX kernel), `Verbatim` (from the `fancyvrb` package), and `lstlisting` (from the `listings` package).

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
in_verbatim = false
function short_words ( s )
  if string.find ( s , "\\begin{[vV]erbatim}" ) or string.find ( s, "\\begin{lstlisting}" ) then
    in_verbatim = true
  elseif string.find ( s , "\\end{[vV]erbatim}" ) or string.find ( s , "\\end{lstlisting}" )then
    in_verbatim = false
  elseif in_verbatim == false then
    s = string.gsub ( s, "(%p)%s+(%u%l?%l?)%s+" , "%1 %2~" ) 
  end
  return s
end
\end{luacode}
%% TeX-side code
\AtBeginDocument{\luadirect{luatexbase.add_to_callback ( 
  "process_input_buffer", short_words , "short_words" )}}

% just for this example
\usepackage[textwidth=0.1mm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
off. The next  

truth? In that case 

off. This fact 

\begin{verbatim}
truth? In that case 
\end{verbatim}

truth? In that case 
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If the document does not contain any verbatim-like environments, the contents of the `luacode` environment may be simplified considerably:

```
\begin{luacode}
function short_words ( s )
    return ( string.gsub ( s, "(%p)%s+(%u%l?%l?)%s+" , "%1 %2~" ) )
end
\end{luacode}
```